# Find the probability of the average weight of smarties given the mean and standard deviation

Tags: probability

Packages of Smarties advertise that they have 63 grams in each package. If the actual weight of smarties followed a normal distribution with a mean of 64 grams and a standard deviation of 2, and you buy 16 randomly selected packages of smarties, what is the probability that the average weight of smarties in the 16 packages is more than 62 grams? Assume the packages are independent.

The answer is $P\bigl(Z> (62-64)/0.5\bigr)$ but I dont see why it wouldn't be $P\bigl(Z>(62-64)/2\bigr)$.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then the average of $n$ independent samples from $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$.

In your case $\sigma=2$, $n=16$.